# Pizza menu design that makes it easy to find the ingredients you want?

Tags: tables, paper

I came across this recently:

[image: bad pizza menu - wall of text]

and I thought it could be improved by extracting the common ingredients into columns, like this:

[image: improved - common ingredients in columns]

[code](https://pizza-menu.glitch.me/)

I find the table intimidating at first. But once you understand it, it is quite empowering.

I was just wondering if there's a better way.

Perhaps the solution lies in combining the columns on the right? Example: half way down, the "Anchovies" column becomes "Tuna".

Comment: There are a number of better ways to design this menu but they would all be based on opinion so not valid here.

Comment: Whatever you do, please add a way for vegetarians to quickly see which entries are suitable like a little green 'v' or something :-)

Comment: I agree the table is more "systematic", allows for a better overview of common ingredients across pizza types, and does not have as much text. Yet, I have (in other list of lists vs. table situations) talked to (even technically-minded) people, who (incomprehensibly to me, but that seems to be a personal (or maybe cultural? That opinion was uttered by Chinese.) bias) insisted the table is very confusing *due to being a table*, because "you have to look to the left *and* to the top to find out what any given cell means".

Comment: "I find the table intimidating at first. But once you understand it, it is quite empowering.": I have no clear answer yet, but this often heard sentence is a strong indicator that the design has serious flaws.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to improve it, i.e. what goal shall be achieved by your improvement? Will the result be on paper or digital?

Answer (score 2):

If this menu is for the customer definitely the table option is not a good idea because the user is not trying to study or work. They just want to eat some pizza.

With all these flavours **will be very hard to do it without images**. See some alternative ideas using images.

[image]
[image]

If the menu is digital then will be hard to give the best way because we can use a lot of resource like javascript to improve a lot the user experience.

**A good suggestion to you is: Look what the biggest pizzerias are doing.**

Comment: "With all these flavours will be very hard to do it without images." - maybe your experience differs, but in my impression, most pizzas with different flavours (excluding some blatant exceptions such as a clearly green rather than red spinach pizza) do not look significantly different, least of all at the first glance on a scaled-down photo. And even if they do, it can be hard to tell what exactly one is looking at (think mincemeat vs. tuna). The second idea, thus, seems much more helpful, especially the *table* part of it.

Comment: I agree with you, but this is not the final design, are just some insights. For my first example, the PizzaHut is showing a zoomed image, then is possible to see the small ingredients. Cheers!